# Understanding how to configure pre-commit with repo: local

Tags: pre-commit.com

I'm trying to get pre-commit working at work (I have it working on personal computer). Our security setup will not allow pre-commit to reference external repos and pip install external packages from them.

It seems like my options are:

1. Keep a copy of needed repositories on local git server
2. Setup .pre-commit-config.yml to use local repo

Before I decide which path to take, I want to know more about how the local repo works, but can't find a lot of documentation on the specifics on the pre-commit website (or elsewhere).

I've got the .pre-commit-config.yml setup like the example below.

```
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        name: Run isort
        entry: isort
        language: system
      - id: black
        name: Run black
        entry: black
        language: system
      - id: flake8
        name: Run flake8
        entry: flake8
        language: system
      - id: pydocstyle
        name: Run pydocstyle
        entry: pydocstyle
        language: system
```

If I use the above .pre-commit-config.yml, what system versions of the packages are used? Is it the version in the active conda environment (I'm using conda)? I thought that would be the case, but the pre-commit hooks appear to be running even though I don't have `isort`, `black`, and `flake8` or `pydocstyle` in the activated conda environment.

That seems odd to me, but I can't find anything online to confirm what system versions of those packages will be used in the local repository setup.

Also, what happens if I use `language: python` instead of `language: system`?

I'm also open if anyone else has any ideas about a way to use pre-commit with the security restrictions I face besides what I've outlined.

Answer (score 21):

repository local hooks are documented [here](https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks)

generally they are the escape hatch for the framework and are generally not the route you should be aiming to take (the suggested route being using the reusable repositories)

`language: system` is an additional escape hatch, in this mode pre-commit **does not manage your tools** and you must install them all manually (this defeats the purpose of the framework entirely, but it enable some amount of legacy compatibility in some use cases).  for `language: system` it will run the tools as if you're running them in your shell (for example `entry: flake8` will use whatever `which flake8` returns)

`language: python` on the other hand is a managed environment, pre-commit will set it up and install it for you.  ~generally if you're using `language: python` with `repo: local` you'll leverage [`additional_dependencies`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-additional_dependencies) to install those things

each of the languages are documented on the website as well

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Anthony - thanks for the info. I appreciate the help and your efforts to create pre-commit. I wanted to clarify a couple other things that I think I understand from the docs, but am not entirely sure. When selecting `types: [python]` will that just run on any Python files in the commit? Also, is there a way to setup pre-commit so it downloads and setups up the needed packages from Anaconda? I have a constraint that things must come from Anaconda's repositories at the moment (which is why I'm considering using the local repo with language: system).

Comment: To clarify, I think I have things figured out, except whether it is possible to have things downloaded from Anaconda's main/conda-forge repositories. Is that currently possible or a potential feature request (e.g. add language: python-conda)?

Comment: there's already a `language: conda` -- and yes `types` controls what files are run on -- that said those are both separate questions (comments get deleted on SO frequently) and may benefit as separate Q&A

Comment: If your pre-commit hooks depend on Python packages that are already specified in a requirements file of some kind, does it still defeat the purpose of the framework to use a local hook? It seems wasteful to create a separate Venv just to run e.g. Flakeheaven, when I already did `pipenv install --dev flakeheaven` and can run it cleanly and safely with `pipenv run flakeheaven`. I'm curious if you think that's some kind of anti-pattern in your framework, or if that's an acceptable/supported use case.

Comment: yes, because I can't just clone your repo and run the tools -- I have to somehow figure out your custom development environment and align all the stars and have everything installed and working

Comment: @anthonysottile Thanks. Came here thinking along same lines as OP. You just helped me understand why pre-commit prefers remote tools over locals.