# How to have a single source of truth for poetry and pre-commit package version?

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, python-poetry, pre-commit.com

I'm looking into [this](https://github.com/br3ndonland/template-python) Python project template. They use `poetry` to define [dev dependencies](https://github.com/br3ndonland/template-python/blob/main/pyproject.toml)

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
black = {version = "*", allow-prereleases = true}
flake8 = "*"
isort = "^5.6"
mypy = ">0.900,<1"
...
```

They use also [`pre-commit`](https://github.com/br3ndonland/template-python/blob/main/.pre-commit-config.yaml) to check housekeeping things (e.g., formatting, linting, issorting, ...), both for git and for CI workflows:

```
minimum_pre_commit_version: 2.8.0
default_stages: [commit, push, manual]
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 21.11b1
    hooks:
      - id: black
  - repo: https://github.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 4.0.1
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
        args: [--max-line-length=88]
  - repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.10.1
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        args: [--filter-files]
  - ...
```

In my case, I definitely want a local version of dev packages managed by poetry for my IDE, and I'd like also to harness the pre-commit framework *"as is"*, without switching to [`language: system`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67796237/4820341). Working this way, I need to manage each package version in two different places.

**Is there a non-manual way to keep dev packages versions (i.e,. `black`, `flake8`, `isort`, `mypy`, ...) aligned to a single source of truth?**  A Coockiecutter template could be an option, but it looks overkilling.

Comment: at some point you'll need the information in two places -- the template has versions also in `poetry.lock` so you'd need some code to synchronize the two

Comment: Yep, true. An option could be using e metatemplate to sync them all. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, I created a pre-commit hook to do the job. See my answer here below

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally, I created a pre-commit hook to do the job: https://github.com/floatingpurr/sync_with_poetry

> Edit: If you use PDM, you can refer to this one: https://github.com/floatingpurr/sync_with_pdm

This hook just keeps in sync the repos `rev` in `.pre-commit-config.yaml` with the packages version locked into `poetry.lock`.

If you use:

- Poetry for dependency management
- local dev packages for your IDE (via Poetry)
- pre-commit hooks

this meta-hook can be useful to (un-)bump repos rev for you.

Comment: I made a tool to do the same job, but with a different approach. Instead of being a pre-commit hook, it's distributed as a plugin for Poetry or PDM. It's heavily inspired by your work, thanks for the inspiration @floatingpurr! https://github.com/GabDug/sync-pre-commit-lock

Comment: Hi @DuGabiche, that's cool! Thank you for sharing this approach

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend keeping the linter stuff only in the config of `pre-commit`.

`pre-commit` doesn't necessarily run as a pre-commit hook. You can run the checks every time by `pre-commit run --all-files` or if you want to run it only on given files with `pre-commit run --files path/to/file`.

You can even say which which check should run, e.g. `pre-commit run black --all-files`

Comment: I see, but I need another copy of them for live interaction provided by the IDE (e.g., VS Code)

Comment: Not sure how it works in VS Code. Because you can run a specific pre-commit check on a specific file  (`pre-commit run <check> --files <filepath>`) it is no problem in PyCharm to run it as in "External Tool". I guess VS Code has something similar.

Comment: *Edited comment*: thanx for your suggestion. Your guess is right. VS Code needs to point at each linter / formatter path that is then passed to the the specified python interpreter. E.g., `"python.formatting.blackPath":"black"`. I've not found a way to pass in the config `pre-commit run black --files <filepath>`. This seems something that does not play nicely with the way VS Code works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @finswimmer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is considered a good practice, solved it by just calling the local, poetry managed version of (e.g.) black like this:

```
repos:
 - repo: local
   hooks:
    - id: black
      name: black
      language: system
      entry: poetry
      args: [ "run", "black", "--config", "black.toml", "--check" ]
      files: [src/]
      types: [python]
```

Edit: I learned that the config is much more complex than just calling the script because pre-commit hook passes the files itself to the program. This could be made easier by using `pass_filenames: false` but I think that will cost you in terms of parallelity and, hence, speed.